# Using the past form of verb "got" with "published"

Tags: tenses

I am currently having confusion to use or not to use the past form of the verb **"get"** with the verb **"publish"**, as in:

1. My first article **got published** in BBC.
2. My first article **published** in BBC.

Is it grammatical to leave out **got**, and just simply say **published**?

Comment: Since You are the not the publisher, you need to use some form of passive there. You could use either _get_, or _be_ there.

Comment: @Cascabel, You mean to say either can be grammatical, if I am not a publisher?

Comment: @Cascabel, isn't it "causative", when I say "got published"?

Comment: @Cascabel, okay, surely.

Comment: "got published" sounds a little informal...I would go with "was published"...in spite of what your professors are probably telling you about passive voice.

Comment: Just to be clear, this has nothing to do with voices (or professors)

Both your examples needed “by the…” not “… in BBC and there are other problems.

“My first article got…” is comprehensible but many speakers agree with me, it is always wrong. Your article didn’t “get” anything; it simply “was…”.

“My first article published…” cannot be understood by itself. It might mean “My first article was published…” but equally, it might mean “The first of several of my articles, all of which were…”